# Is it a good idea to use Optional instead of overloading?

Tags: java, option-type

Compare

```
void doSomething(A a, B b, C c, D d);
void doSomething(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e);
```

with

```
void doSomething(A a, B b, C c, D d, Optional<E> e);
```

which one is a better practice and why?

Comment: The second version sounds incredibly awkward to use.

Comment: really depends on how different the implementation is when E is involved. 

If the implementation is super similiar you could make `void doSomething(A a, B b, C c, D d, Optional<E> e);`

and ALSO overload the two versions, and just have them call the method with the optional. It really depends

Comment: When it's about deciding about Optional or not, think about DRY.